# JMeter File Upload Exception

Tags: exception, file-upload, jmeter

in jmeter 5.6.2 while recording, when I upload a file it is showing
server side exception, failed to upload test.pdf
Debug information:
systemexception: no request files! content-Length: 75919\x0D\x0A at cutewebUI.UploadModule.a(HttpContext A_0, Guid A_1)

I tried using File Upload option of HTTP Request Sampler, there I have given full file path that is stored in jmeter bin folder and gave parameter name as name attribute of browse file element.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to record the file upload event you need to ensure that the file is present in JMeter's "bin" folder prior to executing the file upload in the browser, this way JMeter will generate the appropriate [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager).

There are many different ways to upload a file, the most popular is providing full path, parameter name, MIME-type and ticking "Use multipart/form-data" box:

[image]

If this is not the case - use a 3rd-party sniffer tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to capture the requests originating from JMeter and from the real browser and amend your JMeter configuration so requests would be exactly the same.

More information: [JMeter Performance Testing: Upload & Download Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-testing)